# Definition question.

Tags: soft-question, definition

Suppose we have $x \in \mathbb{R} / [0,1)$.

We call $\lfloor x \rfloor$ the integer part of $x$.

What do we call $\bar{x}=\frac{x}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$???

I would call it fractional part but it doesn't sound right.

Comment: The fractional part $\{x\}$ is actually $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$

Comment: And it is not defined for $x\in[0,1)$.

Comment: @drhab Thanks. I made changes. I am just looking for a good definition (name).